# Code to connect to encrypted / password-protected database

Tags: ms-access, encryption, ms-access-2007, vba

At start up, my front end front.accdr database links to a back end back.accde using:

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "Microsoft Access", "back.accde", acTable, "aTable", "aTable"
```

The back end really needs to be encrypted and so I need to use a password to connect to the encrypted DB. How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method I used to do this is actually quite simple:

```
Set db = CurrentDb
Set dblink = DBEngine.OpenDatabase(strDbFile, False, False, ";PWD=" & strP)

For Each strTable In strLinkedTablesArray
     DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "Microsoft Access", dblink.name, acTable, _
         strTable, strTable
Next
```

Answer (score 4):

If you can't find a way to include the database password with `TransferDatabase`, you can create the table link as a new member of the `DAO.TableDefs` collection.

I confirmed this code works in an Access 2007 ACCDR file.

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim strConnect As String
Dim strDbFile As String
Dim strLinkName As String
Dim strPassword As String
Dim strSourceTableName As String

strDbFile = "C:\share\Access\PasswordEquals_foo.accdb"
strPassword = "foo"
strSourceTableName = "Contacts"
strLinkName = "link_to_contacts"

strConnect = "MS Access;PWD=" & strPassword & _
    ";DATABASE=" & strDbFile
Debug.Print strConnect
Set db = CurrentDb
Set tdf = db.CreateTableDef
tdf.Connect = strConnect
tdf.SourceTableName = strSourceTableName
tdf.Name = strLinkName
db.TableDefs.Append tdf
```

Beware that, even with an ACCDR, anyone who can read the link's `TableDef.Connect` property will be able to see the stored database password.  For example, the following code displays *"MS Access;PWD=foo;DATABASE=C:\share\Access\PasswordEquals_foo.accdb"* in the Immediate window.

```
Dim dbRemote As DAO.Database
Dim objWorkspace As Workspace
Set objWorkspace = CreateWorkspace("", "admin", "", dbUseJet)
Set dbRemote = objWorkspace.OpenDatabase("C:\share\Access\Database2.accdr")
Debug.Print dbRemote.TableDefs("link_to_contacts").Connect
dbRemote.Close
objWorkspace.Close
```

So the link compromises the security of an encrypted db file.

Comment: +1 for the helpful code and explanation (TableDef came in handy elsewhere). The solution for my problem turned out to be much simpler than I expected.